Clio Grow Help- linking my google lead form to Clio Grow with Zapier
I have been trying to get Data from a Google sheet into the Clio Grow API endpoint using Zapier for 2 days now and basic Clio level help has not fixed this
I am getting a 401 error message, here is my data in for the failed ZAP
Any ideas?
payload_type:
json
wrap_in_array:
no
unflatten:
yes
url:
https://grow.clio.com/inbox_leads
data:
inbox_lead_from_first:
Ashoka
inbox_lead_from_last:
Tano
inbox_lead_from_message:
phone@pizzapizza.com
inbox_lead_from_source:
MVA
inbox_lead_referring_url:
google
Inbox_lead_token:
andrea'sinboxleadtokennotreproducedhere
headers:
Accept:
application/json

I expected that the lead would show up in Clio Grow
